# MIPS: 2D Arrays Ordering in Memory

Tags: mips, mips32

**Are 2D arrays in MIPS stored in a column-major order**

[image]

**or row-major order?**

[image]

**If the answer is "by choice" then in this example, my prof is using row-major order implementation purely by choice?**

[image]

Comment: Column vs row is purely a matter of interpretation.

Comment: C uses row major order [as do most languages]. Fortran [generally] uses column major, but current implementations can specify row major for certain arrays [usually for compatibility with C]. Either way, one always wants to access the array such that the _inner_ loop accesses elements that are physically adjacent to get good cache performance [where possible]